# $S_3$ is soluable but not nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Claim: $S_3$ is soluable but not nilpotent

Proof: $S_3 \cong D_6$. $D_6$ has a subgroup of order 3 generated by the rotations, $\langle r\rangle$.

$|\frac{D_6}{\langle r\rangle}|=2$ so $\langle r\rangle \triangleleft D_6$.

Furthermore, $\frac{D_6}{\langle r\rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, and $\langle r\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$,

Therefore we have an abelian series:

$1 \triangleleft \langle r\rangle \triangleleft D_6$

And thus $S_3$ is soluable.

I would be interested in somebody showing me a different way to do this, perhaps in terms of the derived series.

Now, $S_3$ is not nilpotent because $Z(S_3) = \{1\}$

Comment: The centre of a group is never empty --- the identity is in it.

Comment: $S_n$ is soluable if $n<5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the derived series:

Consider the presentation $D_3=\langle r,\bar{r}\mid r^3=\bar{r}^2=1, \bar{r}r=r^{-1}\bar{r}\rangle$.  Note that $D_3'=\langle r\rangle$: since
$$
[r,\bar{r}]=r^{-1}\bar{r}^{-1}r\bar{r}=r^2\bar{r}r\bar{r}=r^2r^{-1}\bar{r}\bar{r}=r
$$
and similarly other commutators all in $\langle r\rangle$.  So the derive series starts
$$
D_3\unrhd D_3'\cong C_3
$$
and now $C_3$ is abelian, so its derived subgroup is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

$S_3$ has a normal solvable subgroup $C_3$ with solvable quotient $C_2$, i.e., $S_3/C_3\cong C_2$. Hence $S_3$ is solvable, too. It cannot be nilpotent, because $Z(S_3)=1$, whereas nilpotent groups have non-trivial center (this was already mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

To show $S_3$ is solvable, note that $G$ is solvable iff $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable for any $N\trianglelefteq G$. Let $N=<(1,2,3)>$. Note that $N$ and $G/N$ are cyclic hence solvable, so, $G$ is solvable. To show $S_3$ is not nilpotent. Note that for a finite group; a group is nilpotent iff it is isomorphic to the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. Observe that the Sylow subgroups of $S_3$ are all cyclic (what are they?). So, their direct product must be abelian, but, $S_3$ is nonabelian!