# Why isn't $Z_2 \times S_3$ nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

I have just learned the definition of a nilpotent group. My book seems to claim that $Z_2 \times S_3$ is not nilpotent, because they say, for the upper central series, $Z(G) = Z_1(G) = Z_2(G) = Z_n(G)$ "has order $2$ for all $n$. But here is my argument that $G$ is nilpotent:

Let $G = Z_2 \times S_3$, and let $Z_2 = \langle x \rangle$. We construct the upper central series. $Z_0(G) = 1 $, and $Z_1(G) = Z(G) = \{(1, 1), (x, 1) \}$. Therefore $G / Z_1(G)$ has order $3$, so it is abelian, and therefore $Z(G/Z_1(G)) = G/Z_1(G)$, so $Z_2(G) = G ,$ and $G$ is nilpotent.

Could you please let me know if my argument is correct, and $G$ is indeed nilpotent? Thank you very much.

Comment: The order of $G$ is $12$, so $G/Z_1(G)$ has order $12/2=6$, not $3$.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 Oh lol thanks

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for your answer! Haha in some cases I made the mistake of forgetting, but in most cases I think the answer just doesn’t address the question fully. In this case I wanted to accept it, but you can’t accept in the first 15 minutes of a question, so I just walked away from the computer with the intent of returning later and accepting. I almost always upvote though.

Comment: Ovi, never mind! Thank you for accepting!. I hope everything is clear with the question. Your question has an upvote, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Haha thanks! (It is Thanksgiving day in the US after all :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every subgroup $H$ of a nilpotent group $G$ is again nilpotent. So suppose that $G=\Bbb Z_2\times S_3$ is nilpotent. Then the subgroup $H=S_3$ is nilpotent. Since nilpotent groups have non-trivial center and $Z(S_3)=1$ this is a contradiction. Hence $G$ is not nilpotent.

Reference: [$S_3$ is soluable but not nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234440/s-3-is-soluable-but-not-nilpotent?rq=1)